# How to merge two files with different number of rows in shell?

Tags: shell, terminal, join, bioinformatics

I have file1 like this:

```
CHR                     SNP     TEST   A1   A2                 GENO   O(HET)   E(HET)            P 
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541      ALL    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan            1
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541      AFF    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541    UNAFF    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255      ALL    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan            1
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255      AFF    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255    UNAFF    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   1                 rs12103      ALL    C    T           55/250/317   0.4019   0.4113       0.5596
   1                 rs12103      AFF    C    T                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   1                 rs12103    UNAFF    C    T                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   1         rs12103_1247494      ALL    C    T           55/250/321   0.3994   0.4097       0.5581
   1         rs12103_1247494      AFF    C    T                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
   1         rs12103_1247494    UNAFF    C    T                0/0/0      nan      nan           NA
```

And file2 like:

```
CHR                     SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541    0    0           NA        0
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255    0    0           NA        0
   1                 rs12103    C    T       0.2894     1244
   1         rs12103_1247494    C    T       0.2875     1252
```

I would like to merge file2 with file1 based on the SNP name and the TEST==ALL and keep the CHR, SNP, P, and MAF in the output file3. Does anybody know the best way for that in terminal (Unix) shell?

A desired output would be:

```
  CHR                     SNP  MAF        P
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541   NA         1
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255   NA         1
   1                 rs12103   0.2894     0.5596
   1         rs12103_1247494   0.2875     0.5581
```

Comment: Please give an example of your desired output.

Comment: How large are the files? Is it possible that at the bottom of file1 there's again a line with 'AFFX-SNP-000541' for the SNP field?

Comment: No. file2's 'AFFX-SNP-000541' is exactly matching with file1's 'AFFX-SNP-000541'+'ALL'.

Comment: Even if it is possible to do this with text files: wouldn't it at some point make sense to import the data into a relational database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files)

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR>1 {a[$2] = $5; next}
     FNR > 1 && ($2 in a) && $3 == "ALL" {
         print $1 "    " $2 "    "  a[$2] "    "  $9
     }' file2 file1
```

To get the header as well, just add this to the beginning of the script:

```
 BEGIN{print "CHR SNP MAF P"}
```

**Explanation:**

First of all, when two files are passed to awk, they are processed one after another. There are two variables important here: `NR` is the line number from the beginning of the `awk` command, and `FNR` is the line number from the beginning of the current file. That is, when the first file is processed (here file2), `NR` and `FNR` have the same value, which is the value of the line currently processed. But when awk pass to second file, `FNR` is reset to 1, so that `NR` and `FNR` are no longer the same. So that the test `FNR==NR` is a trick for knowing if the file processed is the first or not.

So let's see the code. The condition `FNR==NR && FNR>1` tests whether we are processing the first file and not the first line. If it's the case, we store the value of fifth column (`MAF`) in an array indexed by the second one (`SNP`) and then the `next` statement says to pass to the following line.

When awk processes the second file (which is file1), the first test is false, so that awk tries the second test: `FNR > 1 && ($2 in a) && $3 == "ALL"`, that is: not the first line of the file + second column value (`SNP`) exists in table `a` + third column value (`TEST`) is `"ALL"`. If it is the case, then it prints column 1 (`CHR`) and two (`SNP`), gets the `MAF` value from the array with `a[$2]`, and then prints column nine (`P`).

Adding a `BEGIN{...}` statement at the beginning adds a command which is run only before the first line is processed.

Comment: Well, if headers are known, one can add `BEGIN{print "CHR   SNP   MAF   P"}` at the beginning.

Comment: May you be able to give an explanation? Thanks for your great job!

Answer (score 5):

[terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113898/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-the-matching-of-two-columns/113904?noredirect=1#comment176378_113904) mentions doing it with coreutils only, a humble suggestion:

```
(echo CHR SNP MAF P
 paste <(tail -n +2 file2) <(grep ALL file1) | 
   while read -r chr snp _ _ maf _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ p; do 
     echo $chr $snp $maf $p; 
   done) | column -t
```

output:

```
CHR  SNP              MAF     P
0    AFFX-SNP-000541  NA      1
0    AFFX-SNP-002255  NA      1
1    rs12103          0.2894  0.5596
1    rs12103_1247494  0.2875  0.5581
```

Comment: +1 b/c paste is secretly my favorite Unix tool. It can even provide you world peace if you let it 8-)

Comment: @slm - "b/c", what's that?

Comment: @grebneke - b/c = because

Comment: @slm - thanks, that's sorted then. Only world peace to go and we're done.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way of doing it (copy/paste this directly into your terminal):

```
(
 awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{print $1,$2,$5,"P"}' file2;
 awk '$3=="ALL"{print $2,$NF}' file1 | 
  while read snp p; do 
   awk -v snp="$snp" -v p=$p -v OFS="\t" '$2==snp{print $1,$2,$5,p}' file2;
  done
) > file3
```

The output looks like this:

```
CHR SNP MAF P
0   AFFX-SNP-000541 0   1
0   AFFX-SNP-002255 0   1
1   rs12103 C   0.5596
1   rs12103_1247494 C   0.5581
```

#### Notes:

- I am 99% sure you can do this somehow using `coreutils`, perhaps a combination of `sort`,`paste` and `join` but I couldn't figure it out.
- This is not efficient and can take a while if you are dealing with huge files.
- This changes the field separators to tabs, remove all cases of `-v OFS="\t"` if you don't want that.
- As you can see, the fields are no longer aligned. Since they are all separated by tabs, this is not a problem for any programs that will read the file, it is only an issue if *you* try to read it.

#### Explanation

- The 1st `awk` line just prints the 1st, 2nd and 5th field of the header of file 2 followed by `P`. This is the header of the new file.
- The second `awk` prints the 2nd and last (`$NF`) fields of each line of file1 where the 3rd field is `ALL`.
- This is then passed through a shell `while` loop which reads the two fields into the variables `$snp` and `$p`.
- These are then given to the last `awk` using the `-v` option and then, for each line of file2, if the second field is `$snp`, it prints fields 1,2,5 and the current value of `$p`.

---

Here's a perl script that does the same:

```
perl -le 'print "CHR\tSNP\tMAF\tP"; open($f1, "$ARGV[0]"); 
          while(<$f1>){
           s/^\s+//; @f=split(/\s+/); $k{$f[1]}=$f[$#f] if $f[2] eq "ALL"
          } 
          open($f2,"$ARGV[1]"); 
          while(<$f2>){
            s/^\s+//; @f=split(/\s+/); 
            next unless defined($k{$f[1]}); 
            print "$f[0]\t$f[1]\t$f[4]\t$k{$f[1]}"
          }' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
{ printf %s\\n "CHR SNP MAF P"; grep -F ALL file1 | sort -k2,2 | \
join -j2 -o 2.1,2.2,2.5,1.9 - <(sort -k2,2 file2); } | column -t
```

output:

```
CHR  SNP              MAF     P
0    AFFX-SNP-000541  NA      1
0    AFFX-SNP-002255  NA      1
1    rs12103          0.2894  0.5596
1    rs12103_1247494  0.2875  0.5581
```

How it works:

`grep -F ALL file1 | sort -k2` prints the lines matching the string `ALL`, these are then `sort`ed on 2nd field:

```
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541      ALL    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan            1
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255      ALL    0    0                0/0/0      nan      nan            1
   1         rs12103_1247494      ALL    C    T           55/250/321   0.3994   0.4097       0.5581
   1                 rs12103      ALL    C    T           55/250/317   0.4019   0.4113       0.5596
```

this is then joined on 2nd field (`-j2`) with file2 (also sorted on 2nd field) using `-o 2.1,2.2,2.5,1.9` to output 1st, 2nd and 5th field from file2 and 9th field from processed file1:

```
0 AFFX-SNP-000541 NA 1
0 AFFX-SNP-002255 NA 1
1 rs12103 0.2894 0.5596
1 rs12103_1247494 0.2875 0.5581
```

Since this was grouped `{...}` with `printf %s\\n "CHR SNP MAF P"` which prints the header, the entire output is then prettified with `column -t`.
Note that with this solution, lines order (from file2) is not preserved in the output. It just happens that your file2 was already sorted on 2nd field but if it wasn't e.g.:

```
CHR                     SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS
   0         AFFX-SNP-000541    0    0           NA        0
   1                 rs12103    C    T       0.2894     1244
   0         AFFX-SNP-002255    0    0           NA        0
   1         rs12103_1247494    C    T       0.2875     1252
```

and if you wanted to preserve the lines order you could number the lines in file2 with `nl -ba -nrz file2`:

```
000001  CHR                     SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS
000002     0         AFFX-SNP-000541    0    0           NA        0
000003     1                 rs12103    C    T       0.2894     1244
000004     0         AFFX-SNP-002255    0    0           NA        0
000005     1         rs12103_1247494    C    T       0.2875     1252
```

before sorting & joining and adjust the command to: join on 2nd field of (processed) file1 and 3rd field of (processed) file2 and output the line number field + the same fields as the first solution `join -1 2 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.6,1.9` then re-sort the output with `sort -k1n` and delete the first field with  `cut -d' ' -f2-` before piping the entire output to `column -t`:

```
{ printf %s\\n "CHR SNP MAF P"; grep -F ALL file1 | sort -k2,2 | join \
-1 2 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.6,1.9 - <(sort -k3,3 <(nl -ba -nrz file2)) | \
sort -k1n | cut -d' ' -f2-; } | column -t
```

output:

```
CHR  SNP              MAF     P
0    AFFX-SNP-000541  NA      1
1    rs12103          0.2894  0.5596
0    AFFX-SNP-002255  NA      1
1    rs12103_1247494  0.2875  0.5581
```

---

Note that both solutions assume there's only one occurrence of `ALL` on each line, namely the 3rd field (hence the `grep -F ALL`). If that's not the case you'll have to use a regex to filter only the relevant lines.