# How to merge two files based on the matching of two columns?

Tags: text-processing, awk, join, bioinformatics

I have file1 likes:

```
0   AFFX-SNP-000541  NA
0   AFFX-SNP-002255  NA
1   rs12103          0.6401
1   rs12103_1247494  0.696
1   rs12142199       0.7672
```

And a file2:

```
0   AFFX-SNP-000541   1
0   AFFX-SNP-002255   1
1   rs12103           0.5596
1   rs12103_1247494   0.5581
1   rs12142199        0.4931
```

And would like a file3 such that:

```
0   AFFX-SNP-000541     NA       1
0   AFFX-SNP-002255     NA       1
1   rs12103             0.6401   0.5596
1   rs12103_1247494     0.696    0.5581
1   rs12142199          0.7672   0.4931
```

Which means to put the 4th column of file2 to file1 by the name of the 2nd column.

Comment: File2 only got three columns?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This should do it:

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 file2
```

**Important**: this assumes your files are sorted (as in your example) according to the SNP name. If they are not, sort them first:

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)
```

#### Output:

```
0 AFFX-SNP-000541 NA 1
0 AFFX-SNP-002255 NA 1
1 rs12103 0.6401 0.5596
1 rs12103_1247494 0.696 0.5581
1 rs12142199 0.7672 0.4931
```

#### Explanation (from `info join`):

> `join' writes to standard output a line for each pair of input lines
>   that have identical join fields.

```
`-1 FIELD'
     Join on field FIELD (a positive integer) of file 1.

`-2 FIELD'
     Join on field FIELD (a positive integer) of file 2.

`-j FIELD'
     Equivalent to `-1 FIELD -2 FIELD'.

`-o FIELD-LIST'

 Otherwise, construct each output line according to the format in
 FIELD-LIST.  Each element in FIELD-LIST is either the single
 character `0' or has the form M.N where the file number, M, is `1'
 or `2' and N is a positive field number.
```

So, the command above joins the files on the second field and prints the 1st,2nd and 3rd field of file one, followed by the 3rd field of file2.

Answer (score 20):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,h[$2]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

output:

```
$ cat file3
0 AFFX-SNP-000541 NA 1
0 AFFX-SNP-002255 NA 1
1 rs12103 0.6401 0.5596
1 rs12103_1247494 0.696 0.5581
1 rs12142199 0.7672 0.4931
```

Explanation:

Walk through `file2` (`NR==FNR` is only true for the first file argument). Save column 3 in hash-array using column 2 as key: `h[$2] = $3`. Then walk through `file1` and output all three columns `$1,$2,$3`, appending the corresponding saved column from hash-array `h[$2]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just wondering, what does the 'h[$2]=$3' mean? Actually I need to match exactly the file1$2==file2$2 in my complex cases (that are not necessary in same order).

Comment: `h[$2] = $3` is a hash assignment. It save `$3` as the value and `$2` as the key. Example: `h["name"] = "Dadong"`. Now, `print h["name"]` outputs `Dadong`. It does what you want, it matches exactly the second column from both files.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need any ordering, than a simple solution would be

```
paste file{1,2} | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6}' > file3
```

This presumes that all rows have three entries, and column 1 and 2 of both files are the same (as in your example data)

Comment: +1 for great use of `paste`

Comment: @grebneke and Bernhard, since you seem to be fans of `paste` can you figure out a way to answer [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113879/22222) with coreutils?

Comment: @terdon - a humble attempt: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113909/32165

Comment: @terdon I'd advise the to reconsider the program that is outputting this s***

Comment: Nothing wrong with the format, perfectly decent tab separated files. In any case, with this kind of data you usually have no choice as to the format, it comes out of another program.

Comment: @terdon Yeah, that was my way of saying: to complicated for me ;)

Comment: You could golf it shorter with: `paste file1 <(cut -f3 file2) > file3` (assuming tab delimited columns)